# Как можно прописать стиль исключительно для Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, css

Как можно прописать стиль исключительно для Google Chrome?

Comment: Просто делаете стиль и испытываете его на гугл-хроме :) Или надо чтобы работало ТОЛЬКО в хроме, но в других браузерах даже не запускалось?

Comment: да именно так и нужно

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #element { color: red; }
}
```

/ *или* /

```
body:nth-of-type(1) #element { color: red; }
```

Comment: safari также движок webkit использует.